# Ошибка при открытии модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css

С чем связана эта ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
                    <div class="button">
                        КУПИТЬ СО СКИДКОЙ
                    </div>
<script>
        $(document).on('click', '.button', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: '/modal.php',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('body').append(data);
                    yaCounter44605960.reachGoal('forma_zakaza');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.modal').addClass('open');
                    }, 30)
                }
            });
        })
<script>
```

modal.php:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-overlay"></div>
    <div class="modal-window">

        <div class="modal-window-close"><p>Х</p></div>


        <div class="modal-window-header">
            <h1>ОФОРМЛЕНИЕ ЗАКАЗА</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-window-content"><!--

            --><div class="img">
                <img src="images/sh-02-a-.png@crc=303573948">

                <div class="circle">
                    <span class="price">1890</span>
                    <span class="rub"> ₽</span>
                </div>

            </div><!--
            --><div class="form">

                <form method="post">
                    <div class="form__group">
                        <span class="input-container">
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                            <label for="name">Имя</label>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form__group">
                        <span class="input-container">
                            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
                            <label for="phone">Номер телефона</label>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <input class="button" type="button" value="ОФОРМИТЬ" onclick="send_form(this)">


                    <div class="note">Ваш заказ оформлен!<br>Мы перезвоним для подтверждения.</div>
                </form>

            </div><!--
            --></div>
        <div class="modal-window-footer"><!--
            --><div class="modal-window-footer__element">
                <img src="images/w512h5121390857049freeshipping512.png@crc=60072499">
                <div>Время доставки 1-10 дней</div>
            </div><!--
            --><div class="modal-window-footer__element">
                <img src="images/banknotespaymentmoney_billetesdebanco_pag_3773.png@crc=4059188318">
                <div>Без предоплаты.<br>Оплата при получении.</div>
            </div><!--
            --></div>
    </div>
</div>







<script>
    $(document).on('focus', 'input', function () {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('error').addClass('focused');
    })
    $(document).on('blur', 'input', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('focused');
        }
    })
    $(document).on('click', '.modal-window-close', function () {
        var modal = $(this).parents('.modal');
        modal.removeClass('open');
        setTimeout(function () {
            modal.remove();
        }, 300)
    })

    function send_form(elem) {
        var form = $(elem).parents('form');
        var modal = form.parents('.modal');
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: 'send.php',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                try {
                    var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
                    var error_count = Object.keys(json_data.ERRORS).length;
                    if (error_count) {
                        $.each(json_data.ERRORS, function (key, text) {
                            var field_wrap = $(form).find('[name=' + key + ']').parent();
                            field_wrap.addClass('error');
                            //field_wrap.addClass('error').find('.input_error_message').text(text);
                        });
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    modal.find('.modal-window-content').remove();
                    modal.find('.modal-window-header h1').text(json_data.SUCCESS);
                    yaCounter44751631.reachGoal('oform_zakaza');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        modal.removeClass('open');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            modal.remove();
                        }, 300)
                    }, 3000)
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: переменная `yaCounter44605960` не определена

Comment: эта ошибка не относится к вашему коду и никак на него не влияет, просто вы не загрузили скрипт счетчика yandex.

Comment: а вы проверяли, корректно ли подключается скрипт Яндекс API ?